# How to retrieve a specific users' data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a login database with three users. What command do I use
in SQL Server to pull out only one of the users' information?

For example, I have:

```
username: wolf; password: 1234; age:26; hobbies: reading;
username: Tom; password: 1334; age:23; hobbies: smoking;
username: sally; password: 1134; age:30; hobbies: dancing;
```

and I want to display only wolf's information.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = 'wolf'`

Comment: whaT....thats it

Comment: @SebastianBrosch thank you

Comment: You could try reading the most basic of SQL tutorials before asking here.

Comment: I think the question is not clear enough. Can you add more details like the table structure and some sample data? @MARCIOQUITEQUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, What I understood is you have a table with the following details

[image: Sample Table]

And you want to sort only the record of Wolf Like this

[image: Sample Result]

If this is the case then you can just use a simple select Query with a where condition, like this

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE UserName = 'wolf';
```

Comment: thats exactlly it!!